# What's this problem in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, amdgpu

This is my new PC.

- Motherboard: MSI b350 PRO VDH
- Processor: Ryzen 5 2400g APU with radeon vega 11 graphic card
- RAM: 8GB
- SSD: 120GB
- HDD: 1TB

The problem is that I've been trying to install Ubuntu 18.04. But first I have to face `grub installation failed` problem and now this. After reading all about UEFI, EFI partition, bootloader topics, I'm very confused.

After creating EFI partition, there was no problem of `grub installation failed`. But something is still wrong. The PC is frequently stuck while restarting or rebooting.
I have to attempt 2 to 3 times[power on/off] to open ubuntu.
Please help me, I'm really very confused right now.

[Partitions details:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HP2nL.png)

- / 20GB
- /home 95GB
- swap 4GB
- EFI system 1GB

[PC Screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAEQG.jpg)

[PC Screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMRLA.jpg)

[PC Screen 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGKp1.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried booting without splash screen with quiet mode disabled? It's like reading an active log while your system is booting.

Comment: Already tried but nothing happened. But you can tell me your way so I can try that too.

Comment: You did not give detail about how did you install Ubuntu, partitions, warnings... Please, improve your question to help us help you.

Comment: Please, consider improving your question and giving useful detail to help us understand your problem well so as to help you.

Comment: Not boot, but re-boot Try `halt` in the terminal and take a picture of the results when the `System halted` message pops up.

Comment: Same result as PC screen 1 and then system restarted and stuck.

Comment: The PC Screen 1 is when booting. The log should say Stopped or Stopping

Comment: You should describe much more detailed what "stuck" means and what exactly you see if it happens. For instance: what is the difference between "restarting" and "rebooting"? Does some error message appear when it's "stuck"? Does the system still react to keyboard input if it's "stuck"? How _exactly_ are you rebooting the system?